# How to print field in order email?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email, email-templates, transactional-mail

I want print a custom file in order transactional emails.  Here is my Setup file:

```
namespace xxx\xxxx\Setup;

    $quote = $setup->getTable('quote');
    $salesOrder = $setup->getTable('sales_order');


    $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $quote,
        'gst',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' =>'Gst'
        ]
    );

    $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $salesOrder,
        'gst',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' =>'Gst'
        ]
    );

    $setup->endSetup();
```

The function that saves data on order

```
    class SaveOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
   {
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

    $order->setData('gst', $quote->getGst());

    return $this;
}
}
```

The event xml:

```
 <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
```

How to print GST field on user and admin email after order?

Comment: this event working, Issue of print on mail

Comment: You want to display GST field in email?

Comment: thanks @Ranganathan , Yes

Comment: Did you saved value in `quote` table GST column and `sales_order` table GST column?

Comment: yes both table **quote** and **sales_order** save in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="add_custom_variable_to_Order"
            instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ObserverforAddCustomVariable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/ObserverforAddCustomVariable.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ObserverforAddCustomVariable implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
        $order = $transport->getOrder();
        $transport['gst'] = $order->getGst();
    }
}
```

Create custom order email template in `Admin panel->Marketing->Email Templates` and use below code to display in email template

```
 {{var gst}}
```

Check below link to how to override email templates

[Override email templates](https://magefan.com/blog/edit-magento2-transactional-email-template)